# docker-compose.yml to start containers on multiple VM's

Tags: docker

I have created Docker containers using `docker-compose.yml` on a single host.
Can anybody tell if `docker-compose.yml` file can be used to start Docker containers on multiple VMs ? If yes, how?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/key-concepts/

Answer (score 0):

The compose file cannot be used with the new Docker "Swarm Mode" introduced in June (Docker 1.12). The "legacy" Docker Swarm accepts compose files but you should really focus on learning Docker "Swarm Mode", not the old Docker Swarm. It's much simpler too, except for the missing support for compose files.

"swarm mode" accepts dab files and there is a way to convert compose files to dab, but it's experimental (which means that a lot of what you have put in your compose file won't translate). So the current best way is to create bash scripts with the CLI commands eg: `docker service create --name nginx nginx:1.10-alpine`.

and do have look at @Matt 's link about learning the basics of Docker swarm mode. http://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/key-concepts

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly spin up a stack swarm from the external containers and a node list (by ip like 10.0.0.1 or hostname like nodeb):

```
docker run -d -P --restart=always --name swarm-manager swarm manager \
  "nodes://10.0.0.1:2376,nodeb:2376,nodec:2376"

export DOCKER_HOST=$(docker port swarm-manager 2375)

docker-compose up
```

Before running this, you'd need to configure the engines to listen on 2376 with TLS configured, a client key/certificate, and the appropriate network access. See [docker's documentation on TLS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) for more details on configuring this.